# Can we think of immutable lists as a dual to trees?

Tags: list, haskell, data-structures, tree, functional-programming

I might draw a list of words like:

```
this -> is -> a -> test
```

and then through sharing, I might draw two lists as:

```
this -> is -> a -> test
                     ^
                     |
that -> was -> a -> hard
```

Now, if I reverse the arrows, I get a tree, with test as the root.  This is the same notion as duality in graph/category theory.  Therefore, I can think of trees and lists as dual concepts.

Is this correct/useful?

Comment: I think not, because that kind of sharing is not automatic.

Comment: @DanielLyons which means that the dual would be a forest?

Comment: @didierc I think it means the question doesn't really apply.

Comment: that's probably a question for [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com), actually.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sharing and laziness allow you to have arbitrary cyclic structures. For example, in Haskell the definition

```
ones = 1 : ones
```

produces a graph consisting of a single vertex (corresponding to 1) and a loop (in graph-theoretic, not programming sense). By reversing the arrows, you'd get the same structure, and it's not a tree (as it's got loops).

So, it's not true in a lazy language.

Comment: Indeed. It's called "graph reduction" for a reason.